# How can I compile Graphics Gems Books Source Code?

Tags: graphics, rubygems

I have the source code of Graphics Gems for DOS.

I try to compile with DJGPP by running make.

It does nothing. It only says "no makefile found".

I am almost sure that I need an older compiler, but what tools and versions do I need so I can build the library and executable files?

Comment: [tag:compiler-construction] is for questions about constructing (i.e. writing) compilers, not for questions about using them.

Comment: share sample code so we can see what you are dealing with... IIRC makefile is not very MS-DOS times like it was common there was no project or make file you compiled directly the main source code (cpp file where the `main()` function was) and the rest of the stuff was included/linked using `#include` and or `#pragma` directives from the same file not like the crap modern GCC/GC and MS compilers do. The easiest is to use ancient TurboC++ in DOSBox however without seing code we can only guess if that would work or not ... Also what HW are you targeting? MDA/Hercules/CGA/EGA/VGA/VESA ?

Comment: with BIOS or direct I/O or just mapped VRAM access or some gfx api like BGI,Glide? what CPU mode (16bit or 32bit code)? what target (exe,com,ovl)?